# iPhone Web application input field in a position:absolute container

Tags: iphone, css, web-applications, position

I created a group chat for the iPhone and its almost perfect. It uses the complete viewport by position various elements with:

```
#message-input {
background: white;
clear: both;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
```

which makes it look like this:

[image]

But when the keyboard pops everything shifts and a grey area appears below:

[image]

The height of that grey area is the height of the statusbar and the height of the Debug Console together (without the Debug Console is just the height of the statusbar).

Why does it insert this grey area and how can I avoid it?

Comment: its not happening anymore :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
#message-input:focus {
margin-bottom: -XXXpx;
}
```

Where XXX = height of problem grey area. Could be a quick fix for it...